# My source folders are deleted after executing mvn eclipse:eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I execute the command: **mvn eclipse:eclipse** to add the required librairies included in my pom file. The problem is that any **source folder** are deleted after executing that command. 
There is any way to add the libraries without deleting the source folders?

Comment: The goal of `mvn eclipse:eclipse` is to create the Eclipse IDE files (*.classpath, *.wtpmodules and the .settings folder) for use with a project. What do you try to do exactly with ?And what's the plugin's version you use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As allprog wrote: your source folders are probably not deleted. (but probably removed from your .classpath file)

Maven use a standard configuration for all project. Usually there are 2 source folder (for *.java):

- /src/main/java  for your production code
- /src/test/java  for your test code

It's a good practice to follow this recommandations, but you can choose another location for your production/test code by adding this in your pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>test</testSourceDirectory>

    ...
</build>
```

Using multiple source folder for your production code and/or for your test code is not recommended.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you are doing exactly but the `eclipse` plugin handles only eclipse configuration and does not touch any source folders. If the source folders are removed from your eclipse project, then the project/pom file is not set up correctly.

Since Juno, eclipse contains the m2e maven integration plugin. I suggest you create your first projects using that. It will take care of handling the build process and project setup for you.

Use the `New->Project...->Maven Project` menu and create the project using the wizard. When it is complete, copy all your existing sources into the new one and manipulate the pom file with the pom editor (eclipse will open the pom file with this editor by default.)

**Important note**: If you start using m2e, then *don't use* the command line eclipse:eclipse target any more as all the house keeping is done by m2e from that time on. If something is really messes up in your eclipse project, then you may delete the project from the workspace (don't tick the delete from disk option), run eclipse:clean (to make sure everything is cleaned up) and import your project with the m2e importer (File->Import...->Existing Maven Projects...)

Comment: Note that m2e is not compatible with the [Maven Eclipse plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/) which the OP is using. I agree that m2e should be preferred.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. What I'm trying to do is to update the libraries on my project. I've already created a Java project without Maven, and I just wanna add new libraries to my project (using the POM file and Maven). When I use mvn eclipse:eclipse I update my libraries, classpath, etc.) but all my folders configuration is deleted.

Comment: Yes, the eclipse:eclipse command overwrites the .project and .classpath files (and some others). So you have to do all configuration through the POM file. Like this: http://blog.tfd.co.uk/2009/07/29/howto-add-more-than-one-source-directory-into-a-maven-build/